# F# ref cell - behave like pointer vs static variable

Tags: variables, memory-management, static, f#, closures

I am reading F# Wikibooks about [Ref cells](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Mutable_Data#Ref_cells).

It said a ref cell in F# is similar to a pointer in C++, but from [another example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Mutable_Data#Encapsulating_Mutable_State), it seems more like a static variable.

How do the following two functions differ in terms of the actual memory storage?

```
// calling incrPointer() always return 1
let incrPointer() =
    let counter = ref 0
    counter := !counter + 1
    !counter

// calling incrStatic() return 1, 2, 3, ... successively
let incrStatic = 
    let counter = ref 0
    fun () ->
        counter := !counter + 1
        !counter
```

Also, how to make sense of the function below:

```
// calling incrNoPara always return 1
let incrNoPara = 
    let counter = ref 0
    let f =
        counter := !counter + 1
        !counter
    f
```

Thanks All!

Comment: Your question is less about `ref` cells and more about closures, functions, and values. The super-short version (I'll write a more complete answer when I have time) is: `let variable = ref value` creates the ref cell. In `incrPointer()`, that happens every time the function is run, because it happens inside the function, so each time you're incrementing a brand-new ref cell. In `incrStatic`, it happens *outside* the function, so the creation only happens once and then you increment the *same* cell each time. And `incrNoPara` is identical to `incrStatic` -- I'll explain more when I have time.

Comment: any reason why you cannot use `mutable` here? I think past F# 4, there is little need to use `ref`. Not sure about performance implications.

Comment: I wrote that `incrNoPara` is identical to `incrStatic`, but I was wrong. If the line `let f = ...` was `let f () = ...` then it would have been identical. I'll explain more in my answer.

Comment: Just wanted to add that @s952163 is right. That is exactly what "Expert F# 4.0" by D.Syme suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked about ref cells, but the real cause of confusion here is that you aren't yet clear about the difference between how to define functions in F# and how to define values. They look very similar since they're both defined with `let`, but values have no parameters, while functions have at least one parameter (which might be `()`, the so-called `unit` type). Here's a brief illustration of the difference:

```
// This is a value
let foo = 5

// This is a function
let bar x = 5
```

If you write `printfn "%A" foo` in your code, you'll see `5` in the output. But if you write `printfn "%A" bar`, you'll see something like `<fun:it@3-1>`, because `bar` is a function that's waiting for further input. (It ignores its parameter and always returns 5, but it's still a function).

Values and functions can also be defined with blocks of code:

```
// This is still a value
let foo =
    printfn "This will be executed just once"
    5

// This is still a function
let bar x =
    printfn "This will be executed every time bar is called"
    5
```

The other thing you need to know is that when the `ref` keyword appears in a line of code, it creates a new ref cell when that line is executed. If that line appears in a function, it will create a new ref cell every time that function is called. But if that line appears in a value, it will be executed only once in the lifetime of your program.

Now let's look at the three blocks of code that have you confused:

```
let incrPointer() =
    let counter = ref 0
    counter := !counter + 1
    !counter
```

This is a function that, every time it is called, will define a new ref cell containing 0, increment it, and return its value. But when you call the function again, the `ref 0` line gets executed again, defining *another* new ref cell containing 0. The original ref cell is now inaccessible, and will be garbage-collected next time the GC runs. (And once the second run of `incrPointer` has returned, its ref cell is also inaccessible, and will also be garbage-collected at some future point.)

```
let incrStatic = 
    let counter = ref 0
    fun () ->
        counter := !counter + 1
        !counter
```

This, on the other hand, is a named value that contains an unnamed function. When the `let incrStatic = ...` block of code is executed, it first creates a ref cell, and assigns it to the name `counter` (which is not accessible outside this block). Then an unnamed function is created with the `fun () -> ...` syntax. Since it uses the `counter` ref cell, it holds on to a reference to that cell, and so the garbage collector won't collect the `counter` cell as long as this function is still accessible. And since that function is the last expression in the `let incrStatic = ...` block, it becomes the value of `incrStatic`. So now the name `incrStatic` refers to a function that, every time it's called, will increment the *same* ref cell, so you'll see the value that it returns going up by 1 each time. But that ref cell was only created once.

The third block you ask about is this:

```
let incrNoPara = 
    let counter = ref 0
    let f =
        counter := !counter + 1
        !counter
    f
```

You called this a function ("how to make sense of the function below"), but there are no functions here. Both of the `let` expressions in this block have no parameters, so both of them are defining values. What's happening here is:

1. The name `incrNoPara` is declared, which will be a value since it also has no parameters. Its value will be calculated by executing the block of code inside its `let incrNoPara = ...` expression.
2. Inside that expression, a ref cell named `counter` is created and set to 0.
3. Now a name `f` is declared, which will also be a value since it also has no parameters.
4. Inside the `let f = ...` block, the ref cell named `counter` is incremented. Since this name was declared in the enclosing block of code, it's in scope inside the `f` block, so it's no problem accessing it.
5. Next, the value of `counter` (which is now 1 since it was first created with 0 and then incremented just once) is accessed via the `!counter` expression, which returns 1. Since this is the last expression in the `let f = ...` block, this also becomes the value of `f`. So now `f` has been defined as the value 1.
6. Now the value of `f` (which we just set to 1) is retrieved. Since this is the last value in the `let incrNoPara =` block, it becomes the value of `incrNoPara`. Also, since the `counter` ref cell is about to go out of scope and no other code now has a reference to it, it will be marked as garbage and will eventually be garbage-collected.

So now `incrNoPara` has been set to the value 1, and this whole block of code has become a complicated way to write `let incrNoPara = 1` (but creating an extra ref cell that will have to be garbage-collected at some point).

On the other hand, if the `let f = ...` line had simply been `let f () = ...`, then you would have had the following:

```
let incrWithInnerPara = 
    let counter = ref 0
    let f () =
        counter := !counter + 1
        !counter
    f
```

Here, what's going on is the following:

1. The name `incrWithInnerPara` is declared, which will be a value since it also has no parameters. Its value will be calculated by executing the block of code inside its `let incrWithInnerPara = ...` expression.
2. Inside that expression, a ref cell named `counter` is created and set to 0.
3. Now a name `f` is declared, which will be a function since it has a parameter. (Its parameter is `()`, the only instance of the `unit` type). The body of the function will be defined by what's inside the `let f () = ...` block.
4. Inside the `let f () = ...` block, the ref cell named `counter` is incremented. Since this name was declared in the enclosing block of code, it's in scope inside the `f` function, so it's no problem accessing it.
5. Next, the value of `counter` is accessed via the `!counter` expression, which returns its post-increment value. The first time `f()` is called, that value will be 1, but since `f()` might be called multiple times, the value will differ each time `f()` is called. Also, since this is the last expression in the `let f () = ...` block, this also becomes the return value of the `f` function. So now `f` has been defined as a function that increments a counter and then returns its new (post-increment) value.
6. Now the value of `f` (which we just defined to be a function) is retrieved. Since this is the last value in the `let incrWithInnerPara =` block, it becomes the value of `incrWithInnerPara`. Also, the `counter` ref cell is about to go out of scope and no other code now has a reference to it. **But** the `f` function still has a reference to it, and since the `f` function is now the value of `incrWithInnerPara`, there is still a way for outside code to access the value of `counter`. Therefore, the `counter` ref cell will *not* be marked as garbage, and will not be garbage-collected. This is referred to as a "closure": the function `f` has "closed over" the `counter` ref cell. Nothing outside of `f` can access that ref cell, but `f` can still access it, and will do so every time it's called.

Finally, look what happens if we simply add one more set of parentheses to `incrWithInnerPara`, and call it `incrWithOuterPara`:

```
let incrWithOuterPara () = 
    let counter = ref 0
    let f () =
        counter := !counter + 1
        !counter
    f
```

This time, what happens is that every time you call `incrWithOuterPara()`, it creates a new ref cell and returns a new function that has closed over that new ref cell. So you can do something like this:

```
let a = incrWithOuterPara() // Create a ref cell and returns its incr function
let b = incrWithOuterPara() // Create a *different* ref cell and returns a function
printfn "%d, %d, %d" a() a() a() // prints 1, 2, 3
printfn "%d, %d, %d" b() b() // prints 1, 2
printfn "%d" a() // prints 4
printfn "%d" b() // prints 3
```

I hope this helps you understand what's going on. Please feel free to ask questions about anything that's still unclear.

Comment: read through just the first quarter of your answer... must upvote right away! I wish all answers on SO were like that.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Your steps showing the actual working is very useful for understanding. And I didn't think of function and value as two distinct concepts. It is a new idea for me!